# Can't push a view from a modal view in iOS5

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, ios5, ios4

I have a Navigation Controller based app.  From my Root VC, I have one view that I present modally like this:

```
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:shortcutsViewController animated:YES];
```

shortcutsVC contains a row of buttons, which take the user to various places in the app.

In iOS 4.3, this works:

```
UINavigationController *saveNavigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.parentViewController;
[saveNavigationController pushViewController:multipleListViewController animated:YES];
[saveNavigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[multipleListViewController release];
```

It does not work if the dismiss happens before the push.

In iOS 5, it doesn't work at all, regardless of which order the two commands are in.

By "not work" I mean that the button highlights briefly but the new VC is not displayed.

What is the right way to do this?  Or am I doing something that was illegal all along and just happened to work in 4.3?

EDIT:

I got some offline help on this one.

The problem is that in iOS5, parentViewController has been renamed presentingViewController.  Since I still need to support both 4.x and 5.x, I changed this

```
UINavigationController *saveNavigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.parentViewController;
```

to this

```
UINavigationController *saveNavigationController;
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(presentingViewController)]) {
    saveNavigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.presentingViewController;
} else {
    saveNavigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.parentViewController;
}
```

And all is happy now.